# Loss of optical fibers -- where is the limit?

Tags: fiber-optics, amorphous-solids

I'm wondering what is the physical limit of loss in optical fibers. How much of the loss, that can be seen in today's optical fibers can be removed by optimizing the production procedure and how much of it is due to a physical limit.

The world record that i found so far is 0.1419 dB/km [1].  Apparently about 80% of the losses of current single mode fibers is due to Rayleigh scattering, which is mainly caused by fluctuations in the density and dopant concentration.

In the paper above, the authors achieved an improvement in using a pure silica core, where most of the light propagates, so that only the "tails" of the single mode are propagating into the doped part, where the fluctuations of the dopant can lead to Rayleigh scattering.

Another improvement is given because the material relaxation was improved. Apparently, when the material cools down, little structural defects are frozen into the material and if cooled too quickly, they remain there [2]. The  temperature at which the structure does not change anymore while cooling down, is the fictive temperature $T_f$, which has been linked to the loss of a fiber [2]. There seem to be some ways of reducing this fictive temperature and improving the cool-down further [3], but how far can it be reduced.

I know that for crystals, there are thermodynamic arguments that crystalline structures can not be without defects at temperatures above 0 K. Are there similar considerations about how much the fictive temperature of an amorphous solid can be reduced?

[1] https://global-sei.com/technology/tr/bn86/pdf/86-04.pdf

[2] https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7537487

[3] https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.122129

Comment: can we take that 4 significant digits claim seriously in the figure 0.1419dB/km?

Comment: @hyportnex - depends on how many kilometers of fiber they used and how good their calibration was... I didn’t read the article...

Comment: Yeah, they don't discuss the certainty of their results in the paper. However, the main claim of the paper would also work with 3 significant digits. I believe them that they improved the transmission of the fibers.